# Problems with some grammar in ANTLR

Tags: c#, antlr

I've been doing an excersise that consists on read from a text file and:

- Replace consecutive spaces/tabs with only one space
- Replace consecutive newline characters with only one
- Make all the text upper-case.

When I execute it, it doesn't write anything to the `output.txt` file...

I've been trying to find the problem for a while without success. Here is my code:

```
grammar Ejerc1;
options
{
    language = CSharp3;
}
@header
{
using System.IO;
using System;
}
fragment Spaces     :   (' '|'\t')+ { $text = " "; };
fragment Any        :   (~(' '|'\t'|'\n'|'\r'))+ { $text = $text.ToUpper(); };
fragment NewLines   :   ('\r'|'\n')+ { $text = "\r\n"; };

/* Parser */
public file[string filePath]
@init {
if (File.Exists($filePath)) { 
    File.Delete($filePath); 
}
StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter($filePath);
}
@after {
w.Close();
}
:
(
 Spaces { w.Write($Spaces.text); }
|NewLines { w.Write($NewLines.text); }
|Any { w.Write($Any.text); }
)*
EOF;
```

and here is the code inside the `Main` method:

```
string inputPath = "text.txt";
string outputPath = "output.txt";
var input = new ANTLRFileStream(inputPath);
var lexer = new Ejerc1Lexer(input);

var tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
var parser = new Ejerc1Parser(tokens);
parser.file(outputPath);
```

Comment: Haven't played much with v3, but I found this comment in a tutorial: "A lexer rule can refer to other lexer rules. Often they reference 'fragment' lexer rules. These do not result in creation of tokens and are only present to simplify the definition of other lexer rules." Perhaps removing 'fragment' from the definitions will help? Also, instead of `Spaces { w.Write($Spaces.text); }`, try `sp=Spaces { w.Write($sp.text); }`.

Comment: @OwenS. Thanks. That was the problem. Also, could you explain why do you suggest doing `sp = Spaces...` instead of doing it directly?

Comment: there is no difference between `Spaces { w.Write($Spaces.text); }` and `sp=Spaces { w.Write($sp.text); }`. The latter is used when two the same tokens or productions are used: `foo : Token Token ;`. To reference one of them, then a "label" is assigned to them: `foo : a=Token b=Token {... $a.text ... $b.text ... } ;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fragment rules can only be used from other lexer rules, ***not*** from parser rules, as you're trying to do. Simply remove the `fragment` keywords from your 3 lexer rules.

Also, the snippet:

```
$text = " ";
```

translates to the following (pseudo code):

```
getText() = " "
```

which is not valid (at least, when using the Java target it's invalid). You might want to try:

```
Spaces     :   (' '|'\t')+ { SetText(" "); };
```

instead. But the CSharp3 target might just accept it though.

Comment: That did the trick :) And about doing `SetText(...)`, thanks for the advice. It is good to know that, although in CSharp3 it seems to be valid ;)

Comment: That made totally sense after knowing what is the meaning of *fragment* rules ;) If a fragment rule won't become a token, how is the parser supposed to work with it? :)

Comment: @Oscar, nice to know CSharp3 accepts it. The Java target _does_ accept `$type = SOME_TYPE`, so I've always found it odd why `$text = "some text"` doesn't work. And you're welcome of course!